# How to sort array numbers by absolute value

Tags: python

Given an array of ints:

```
(-20, -5, 10, 15)
```

the program should output:

```
[-5, 10, 15, -20]
```

I first tried to think about the pseudocode:

for each element in the array
  if its absolute value is higher than the nxt element
  swap them

And I implemented this as:

```
def sort_by_abs(numbers_array: tuple) -> list:

    numbers_array = list(numbers_array)

    for i, number in enumerate(numbers_array):
        if i == len(numbers_array) - 1:
            break
        elif abs(number) > abs(numbers_array[i+1]):
            temp = number
            numbers_array[i] = numbers_array[i+1]
            numbers_array[i+1] = temp


    return numbers_array
```

However it fails when we have the following sequence:

```
(1, 2, 3, 0)
```

it outputs

```
[1, 2, 0, 3]
```

And I understand that when the element which needs to be moved is not at first there could be other numbers to be moved to the left

Then I tried sorting the list first, and it solves this case:

```
def sort_by_abs(numbers_array: tuple) -> list:

    numbers_array = sorted(list(numbers_array))

    for i, number in enumerate(numbers_array):
        if i == len(numbers_array) - 1:
            break
        elif abs(number) > abs(numbers_array[i+1]):
            temp = number
            numbers_array[i] = numbers_array[i+1]
            numbers_array[i+1] = temp

    return numbers_array
```

However when we have: `(-1, -2, -3, 0)` it outputs `[-2, -1, 0, -3]` and it should return `[0, -1, -2, -3]`

**How could be it improved?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use python builtin [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with key `abs` which sorts considering the absolute value of the integer

```
def sort_by_abs(numbers_array):

    return sorted(tuple(numbers_array), key=abs)

print(sort_by_abs((-5, 10, 15, -20)))
print(sort_by_abs((-1, -2, -3, 0)))
print(sort_by_abs((1, 2, 3, 0)))
```

The output will be

```
[-5, 10, 15, -20]
[0, -1, -2, -3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```